# How to use CHttpCookie in Yii2

Tags: cookies, yii2, httpcookie

**I have code bellow**

```
use yii\web\CHttpCookie;

$user_identifier = md5(rand()); 
$cookie = new CHttpCookie('user_identifier', $user_identifier);
$cookie->expire = time() + (60*60*24*365*5);
```

But output error, Please tell me how to use HttpCookie

```
Class 'yii\web\CHttpCookie' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no classes with `C` prefix in Yii2. The equivalent in Yii2 will be:

```
// get the cookie collection (yii\web\CookieCollection) from the "response" component
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

// add a new cookie to the response to be sent
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'user_identifier',
    'value' => md5(rand()),
    'expire' => time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5,
]));

// remove a cookie
$cookies->remove('user_identifier');
// equivalent to the following
unset($cookies['user_identifier']);
```

It's covered in official docs in paragraph ["Setting Cookies"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#sending-cookies) in ["Cookies"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies) section.